# undeclared identifier 'UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification' when compiling with apportable

Tags: ios, apportable

I'm getting the below error when trying to compile our iOS app using Apportable:

> use of undeclared identifier 'UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification'; did you mean 'UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification'?

The line of code it is failing on is:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textChanged:) name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

XCode says that UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification is a valid Notification. Any insight into this would be great. In the mean time I'll continue searching.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you putting that line of code?

Comment: please explain whole situation,what you are using, what you want to achieve?

Comment: It's actually part of KTTextView (https://github.com/kirbyt/KTTextView) so it's not my code. However, the code compiles and runs fine in XCode, just not in Apportable. I assume the issue is not in the Objective-C code exactly but has to do with the libraries and headers in Apportable. Perhaps it's not implemented. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification is not yet implemented in the Apportable platform.

Note that it is missing from $HOME/.apportable/SDK/System/UIKit/UITextView.h